# SQLite Phone Gap db transaction not saving some records on insert

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

```
    dbShell.transaction(function(tx) {
       for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++ ){
            var sql ="Insert into students(studentid,name) SELECT '"+ data.studentid +"', '"+ data.name +"' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM students WHERE studentid ='" + data.studentid +"')";
                            tx.executeSql(sql, [], nullHandler,dbErrorHandler);
            }
    });
```

I get data (student list) in json format. I do insert query in sqlite phonegap by looping on the data recieved. But the insert statement does not same some records. I feel it is because the transaction is not completed.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong in this query?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for insert:

```
dbShell.transaction(function(tx) {
   for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++ ){
        var sql ="Insert into students(studentid,name) values(?,?)";
        tx.executeSql(sql, [data[i].studentid, data[i].name], successHandler,errorHandler);
   }
});
```

You need to add successHandler and errorHandler

Comment: What difference will it make  replacing nullhandler with suceesshandler? I dont want to do anything when the insert is executed but just execute the next insert statement.

Comment: successHandler is required when you want to perform some operation after query insertion. If you don't use successhandler, you will not able to know when query execution completed successfully.

Comment: my nullhandler is the success handler its just the naming mate. I found the problem. And already answered it.

Comment: If you have use bind parameters, you might not have faced issue of single quote.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. the problem was in the json data that I received. One of he names contained ' single quote in the name. this caused the query to fail.